# How to wrap a input button by form tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So the following tables are generated from backend where I load CSV and used pandas.style to make some column as an input text field and a button. I applied the same function on all of the value of the column but the thing is all the column 1 has the form tag except the one that is row 0 element. You can see from the below table. When I do view page source I am able to see the form tag on the first row also but inspect elem doesn't show it. So one thing I can think of is to use javascript and add form tag but I don't know how to do it.

```html
<table id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="blank level0" ></th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >x</th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >y</th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >z</th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >s</th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >t</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >0</th>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >123</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" ><input name="id_request" type="submit" value="hab123" /></td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >0</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >0.0254823</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row0_col4" class="data row0 col4" ><input name="prob" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="1" value="0.25" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >1</th>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >145</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >
            <form method="POST" ><input name="id_request" type="submit" value="hab234" /></form>
        </td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >0</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >0.0160481</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row1_col4" class="data row1 col4" ><input name="prob" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="1" value="0.0" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >2</th>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >567</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >
            <form method="POST" ><input name="id_request" type="submit" value="hab056" /></form>
        </td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >0</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >0.0297317</td>
        <td id="T_8ee5b050_16c9_11ea_97a1_9d9fe3c434b2row2_col4" class="data row2 col4" ><input name="prob" type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an element in Javascript, you must use `document.createElement` (so, here, `document.createElement("form")`). However, I just do not understand why your form doesn't appear. See if it is not linked with the fact that the 2 `input`s have the same name.

Comment: the thing is I know how to append, prepend but the case here is tricky first I have to go to tr (data row0 col1) then I have to get the input elem and here you can see it doesn't have any class name.

Comment: to get the input you can search it with the vlue attribute which is unique

Comment: Thing is I am using pagination. It's not that simple you thing. this problem occurs for 1st row only.

Comment: What you are saying is hardcode thing but there are 40 pages and I won't be knowing their value. User will upload his/her csv .